# Owner is null after insert - Test class

Tags: unit-test, ownership

I have to test the results of a query like this:

```
[SELECT Id, Owner.Name FROM MyObject__c]
```

which is called in the constructor of a visualforce page. The Owner.Name is diplayed in the page. The page works fine and I can read the names.

In the unit test though...

```
User u = [SELECT Id, Name From User..]; //some User
System.runAs(u){
    testObj = new MyObject__c(Field__c='test',OwnerId=u.Id);
    insert testObj;
}

/*
..test goes on, the contructor of the page is called and finally the query arrives:
*/

MyObject o = [SELECT Id, Owner.Name, OwnerId FROM MyObject__c WHERE..]

//o.OwnerId = correct Id
System.assertEquals(u.Id, o.OwnerId); //ok


//o.Owner = null
//o.Owner.Name = null
//...how does this work?
System.assertEquals(u.Name, o.Owner.Name); //not ok
```

Any insight?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you doing this query  MyObject o = [SELECT Id, Owner.Name, OwnerId FROM MyObject__c WHERE..] in the test class?

Comment: No, it is done in the controller of the page, I create one controller instance in the test. (but yes, I also tried that query in the test, with the same result)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

salesforce known bug :

None of the owner fields are accessible in a test class

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SwHDAA0

**Interesting fact 1:** when you use `myobject.ownerid` assertion passed but when you do `myobject.owner.id` assertion fails

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 005d0000001U4iVAAS, Actual: null
```

**Interesting fact 2:** field name typo in the bug heading :P

While Using SeeAllData=false, owner ***filed*** not visible in SOQL on Custom Objects

Comment: what about in 2023?